# IntelliJ - Debugging process started by new process

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, process, intellij-13

I have a given jar file. It should be run with an argument which starts up another java process (my program).

I use a process builder to start a process (givenJar). Within this process, my program is started.

```
MyMain1: run processBuilder -> "java","-jar","givenJar.jar","java -cp myPath MyMain2"}
```

My problem is : How do I attach debugging? Is it possible?

I hope, that it makes sense... ;-)

Comment: Just use Remote debug configuration, IntelliJ IDEA will suggest you the options to pass to your process.

Comment: Ah ok. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok....

I solved it:

1. Edit configurations
2. Choose MyMain2
3. In "Defaults" go to "Remote"
4. Copy command line
5. Go back to Application/Main2
6. Insert command line in "Program arguments"